# Redirection from logout.php page to index.php doesn't work

Tags: php

I have a logout.php page that is linked in a pagetop.php however when a logged in user presses the logout button it doesn't redirected them back to the index page.

logout script:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

This is the href code found in my pagetop.php page:

```
 <?php

 if($_SESSION['loggedin'] != TRUE){

echo "Already a member?&nbsp;
 <form id=\"loginform\" method=\"post\" action=" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "
 <label for=\"username\"> Email Address:</label>
 <input type=\"text\" name=\"liusername\"/>
 <br>
 <label for=\"password\"> Password:</label>
 <input type=\"text\" name=\"lipassword\" id=\"password\" />
 </div>
 <div class=\"submit\">
 <input name=\"lisubmit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\">
 </div>\n";

 }else{
echo "<a href = logout.php>Log out</A>\n";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Try placing `ob_start();` at the beginning of your logout page

Comment: Sure you didn't forget ' around the logout.php in the A tag?
`echo "<a href = 'logout.php'>Log out</a>\n";`

Comment: Have you checked this line **echo "<a href = logout.php>Log out</A>\n";**, it's missing quotes. It should go like this **echo "<a href = 'logout.php'>Log out</A>\n";"**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code is perfact but a little mistake here 
Remove `$_SESSION = array()`

Here `$session` is already started so it will remove and `header()` is used to redirect page to another page.

```
<?php
  session_destroy();
  header('Location: index.php');
  exit();
?>
```

Comment: Its Better to post reason for -1 that Other can improve their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Delete `$_SESSION = array()` and add `exit;` after `header();`. You are overwriting your global variable with the session assignment and `session_destroy()` clears **actual** session so it clears nothing. Also exit after header is a good habit, even tho you do not have any script after it you should always prevent from executing the scripts below `header()`.